# Sunpath at particular location in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pvlib, solar

How can i find out sun position at a particular location with consideration of surroundings such as trees, nearby buildings etc., to calculate to irradiation coming to the PV module?

How can i create a horizontal shading profile to find shading factor?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3fJM.png): example sunpath
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIXwR.png): Reference code azimuth vs altitude

Comment: Just as a comment, if you use irradiance data from PVGIS e.g., the pvlib.iotools.get_pvgis_tmy() function, then it is possible to take into account far-field shading from hills using the `usehorizon` argument. But this does not account for not trees and buildings - see this [discussion](https://github.com/pvlib/pvlib-python/pull/758).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.